# <ol type="A"> not working insider table columns in mPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table, html-lists, mpdf

I have a problem. Inside the table column, `<ol type="A">` not working.

[image: view images]

Here my code applied in mpdf_view.php

```php
<?php  $html=   '   
<table>
<tbody>
';

$html.='
<tr><td>Menimbang</td><td>:</td>
<td>

<ol type="a">
<li>Text here lorem ipsum ibisque totum.</li>
<li>Text here lorem ipsum ibisque totum.></li>
</ol>';


$html.=' 
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
';


$html.='</body>
</html>';

///////////////////////////
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output();

////////////////////////
?>
```

## [Download MPDF](http://www.damaruta.com/2019/02/cetak-pdfmenggunakan-mpdf-pada.html) libraries/mpdf

There M_pdf.php in folder libraries/

```php
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
//include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';
require_once dirname(__file__).'/mpdf/mpdf.php';
class M_pdf {
    public $param;
    public $pdf;
    public function __construct($param = "'c', 'A4-L'")
    {
        $this->param =$param;
        $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
    }
}
```

===

My controller:

```php
public function print_mpdf()
    {
        $this->load->library('M_pdf');
        $this->load->view('mpdf_view');
```

Comment: what is your problem? post your code here not just images

Comment: Please read [ask] and then update your post  so it follow SO guidelines.

Comment: Thanks. Im update my ask.

Answer (score 2):

The **new question** is about why the `mpdf` library does not display `<ol>` with the applied styling/type. According to the `mpdf` manual on [HTML support](https://mpdf.github.io/html-support/html-attributes.html) `type` attribute is supported in `<ol>` html elements.

**Note:** This is answer to original question about displaying `<ol>` list with lower-case letters in html.

There are two options here either use the [`type` html attribute of `<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) which supports `1` (numbers), `a`,`A` (lower-case or upper-case alphabetic letters) and `i`,`I` (lower-case, upper-case roman numerals), or use css styling with [`list-style-type` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) with even more options

Use `type` html attribute (recommended if using `mpdf`):

```html
<ol type="a">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ol>
```

Use `list-style-type` css property (recommended for html in general):

```css
ol.alphabetic-list {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

```html
<ol class="alphabetic-list">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using '=' operator in type.

```
<ol type="a">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The result is not  a. b. c. in list. But 1. 2. 3.

Comment: <table><tr><td><ol type="a">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ol></td></tr></table>   If this apply in the column of table, the result is not a. b. c, but 1, 2, 3. I need result is a, b, c.

Comment: @EdiHaryono I think it's time for a coffee https://jsfiddle.net/6qsrkeuj/ - and please stop using w3schools as a learning resource. They're really, really bad.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be the browser is applying some styles that cancel the default styling behavior (there is some rule in some place).

Be sure to inspect in the browser the rules been applied to the `ol`. Double-check there is nothing like:

**Wrong**

```
ol { list-style: none; }
```

If that is the case be sure of applying the proper styles like for example:

**OK**

```
ol { list-style: upper-latin inside; }
```